# How to check BoundingSphere for one ModelBone?

Tags: xna-4.0

Like this title question. How to check BoundingSphere for one ModelBone in XNA 4.0??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One ModelBone is one mesh in model. You need determined mesh to check and use property: mesh.BoundingSphere to check ModelBone you want to check.